# grabbing column data using procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to take two parameters. a customer id and a purchase amount. The purchase amount is not in the table i will be referencing. it is going to be compared to the credit limit assigned to said customer id and do a dbms output of ethier the credit is too low for the allowed amount or its fine.

I am having trouble implementing the procedure to take the purchase amount parameter and comparing it to the actual credit limit in the table

```
create or replace PROCEDURE check_available_credit(
c_cust_id IN demo_customer.custid%TYPE,
c_purchase_amount IN NUMBER
) AS c_credit_check VARCHAR(50);

climit       demo_customer.creditlimit%type;

BEGIN
SELECT climit
    INTO c_credit_check--PLACE INTO PROCEDURE
    FROM demo_customer
    WHERE custid = c_cust_id;
         if(c_purchase_amount > climit)
         THEN dbms_output.put_line('Amount is too high');
         elsif(c_purchase_amount < climit)
         THEN dbms_output.put_line('Amount is perfect');
         COMMIT;
        END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        END check_available_credit;
```

I will be using 100 for the custid and 4000 for the purchase amount. that will pull the record of a customer whos credit limit is 5000 so it should report "amount is perfect"

Answer (score 0):

You have used `climit` in the select statement incorrectly. I'm not sure by the way why you're using the variable `c_credit_check`.

The below procedure seems to work with the above mentioned change. For the exception block I've added a `dbms_output` to display the error stack. `Rollback` is not needed unless you've got other DMLs in your procedure body. Commit should ideally be in the calling section and can be removed if there are no DMLs

**Test table / data**

```
    create table demo_customer( custid int,creditlimit number );
    insert into demo_customer(custid,creditlimit) values (100,5000);
```

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_available_credit(
     c_cust_id IN demo_customer.custid%TYPE,c_purchase_amount IN NUMBER
) AS
     climit       demo_customer.creditlimit%TYPE;
BEGIN
     SELECT creditlimit
        INTO climit
    FROM demo_customer
    WHERE custid = c_cust_id;

     IF(c_purchase_amount > climit )
         THEN dbms_output.put_line('Amount is too high');
     ELSIF ( c_purchase_amount < climit ) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Amount is perfect');
          --COMMIT; --not needed if there are no dmls, move this to calling 
                    --block if there are any.
     END IF;

EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK; --not needed unless there's a dml
       dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
END check_available_credit;
```

**Execution**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
 check_available_credit(100,4000);
END;
/  

Amount is perfect


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```